# textfield shouldChangeCharactersInRange not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift2

Issues:

Text fields are not accepting characters.

`shouldChangeCharactersInRange` not being called for all 3 text fields.

I have 3 delegate classes implemented just like in `main`. With all the methods implemented exactly as the delegate methods are implemented in `main`. All the other methods except `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` are called during run-time. The editbox simply isn't accepting any character.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!

    var t1Delegate : text1Delegate!
    var t2Delegate : text2Delegate!
    var t3Delegate : text3Delegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {   
             t2Delegate = text2Delegate()
        textField2.delegate = t2Delegate
     }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        textField1.delegate = self
        textField1.becomeFirstResponder()
        t3Delegate = text3Delegate()
        textField3.delegate = t3Delegate
        super.viewDidLoad()   
    }
    func textField (textField :  UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range:  NSRange, replacementString string:  String  )  ->  Bool {
        print("*. Should change text.")
        return true;   
    }
    // UITextField Delegates
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        print("*. TextField did begin editing method called")
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        print("*. TextField did end editing method called")
    }
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("*. TextField should begin editing method called")
        return true;
    }
    func textFieldShouldClear(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("*. TextField should clear method called")
        return true;
    }
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("*. TextField should end editing method called")
        return true;
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("*TextField should return method called")
        textField.resignFirstResponder();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the code you provided, the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method in your code will only be called for `textField1`.

Comment: Did you connect the IBOutlets??

Comment: yeah each IBOutlet (from the little dot left of the declaration line) is connected to each textfield in storyboard.

Comment: To rmaddy, the delegate method in my code is only connected to textField1. Other textFields are connected to user-defined delegate class text2Delegate and text3Delegate respectively. These delegate classes are implemented just as the delegate methods in main (plain -only printouts)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0 Change Textfield editing method.
Please use with below attached method

```
class PromoCodeViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate{
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tf_GiftVoucher.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if tf_GiftVoucher == textField {
        let text = textField.text
        if (text?.characters.count)! > 15 || string == " " {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```